# Use `/*` instead of `//` for file header

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

The file header generated by ReSharper use `//` to 'escape' it.

Actually I got this:

```
//
// This file is part of the Software I Work On
//
namespace Com.This.Is.Not.Java
{
    class MyClass
    {
    }
}
```

**Edit** Note the *commented* blank line before the namespace, to get it, I put two blank lines at the end of ReSharper file header template.

I would like to got this:

```
/*
 * This file is part of the Software I Work On
 */
namespace Com.This.Is.Not.Java
{
    class MyClass
    {
    }
}
```

**Add** We are actually migrating from VS2013 to VS2015. To manage file header we use an internally developed extension that produce `/*` escaped header. We do not want to maintain this extension that is not compatible with VS2015. So we are thinking about using ReSharper to manage headers.

Two options:

1. ReSharper produce a header compatible with the previous tool (`/*` escaped).
2. We remove the old tool (can't be done without re-install VS2013), we push a big commit that replace the `/*` escaped headers by the `//` ones.

Option *1* is way more cheap.

Comment: `//` is the recommended way of commenting code because you can uncomment or commment code using keyboard shortcuts while using `/*` you can't..

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer What does that have to do with a file header???????

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer, don't comment out code. Delete it. If you need it back, pull it back from a commit to git/TFS.

Comment: @DavidArno I know it... but you might need to comment / uncomment even before committing code......................................

Comment: @kevintjuh93 It makes sense, because it seems like watching an asterisk in your file header it can make your productive day complicated, or who knows ;)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer, actually this make my day complicated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is currently [a known issue with ReSharper](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-437129). The [History](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-437129#tab=History) indicates that in April 2015, it acquired an assignee and its priority was raise to Critical, so you may get a fix fairly soon.

Comment: Many thanks, I didn't find the issue in RSRP by myself.